# How to specify both default and named external import as output.globals in rollup.js?

Tags: typescript, rollupjs

I cannot find how to specify both default and named import as output.globals using rollup.js (v1.27.0)

I am using apprun.js as external  in html file.

My index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/apprun@1.22.2/dist/apprun.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="x.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

where x.js is compiled by rollup from x.tsx below:

```
import app, {Component} from 'apprun'

class Page extends Component {
    view = (s) => <div>Main Page</div>
}
app.render(document.body, <Page />)
```

Without the need to install apprun.js locally, I only need to download `https://github.com/yysun/apprun/blob/master/apprun.d.ts` to the same location as `x.tsx` to pass the typescript type checker. Installing apprun.js locally doesnt help in this case, anyway.

My rollup.config.js

```
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript'
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'
const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH
export default {
    external: ['apprun']
    , input: 'x.tsx'
    , output: {
        file: 'x.js'
        , format: 'iife'
        , globals: {
            apprun: 'app'  // <<-- how to add 'Component' also?
        }
    }
    , plugins: [
        typescript()
        , production && terser()
    ]
}
```

rollup -c -w gives x.js

```
    var Page = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
        __extends(Page, _super);
        function Page() {
            ...
            return _this;
        }
        return Page;
    }(app.Component));    // <<--- app.Component is undefined, should be Component
    app__default.render(document.body, app__default.createElement(Page, null));
}(app));
```

On the 3rd line from last, `app.Component` should be just `Component`, as seen in apprun.d.ts

Any advice on how to configure rollup so that both `app` and `Component` are treated as globals at the same time?
Thanks!

Comment: By chance did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I have since moved on.